# Liquid markup in Java/Scala

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, scala, markup, liquid

I'm looking analogs for Rails [Liquid markup](http://liquidmarkup.org/)! in Java or Scala languages. Which markup exists like liquid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also take a look at [**Handlebars.java**](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java).

You can make `Helper`s to emulate Liquid's filters:

**Liquid:**

```
 {{ context | markdownify }}
```

**Handlebars.java:**

```
 {{md context}}
```

Answer (score 5):

I was also looking for a java implementation of Liquid, and found this: https://github.com/bkiers/Liqp

According to the author, Liqp is:

> An ANTLR based 'Liquid Template' parser and rendering engine.

Answer (score 4):

[Scalate Mustache](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/mustache.html)

May do the trick, offers pre-compilation, and "codeless" templates (although I am not sure if the security requirement of Liquid is fully met).

At any rate, check it out, the Scalate template engine itself is quite powerful (jade, scaml, etc.)...

Comment: Hi! I know about scalate project, but I will look at mustache soon. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The most similar I can think of is probably [Jangod](http://www.jangod.org/). I guess you be able to use Liquid directly with the help of JRuby. Alternatively you can use some classic markup format like [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/). Another suggestion that I haven't personally tried would be [Mustache.java](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java).